# Python TypeError when using iteration to find max and min

Tags: python, error-handling

1. The error message is：

   > Traceback (most recent call last):
   >
   > File "C:/1-Python/2-projects/最值.py", line 18, in 
   >   elif findMinAndMax([7]) != (7, 7):
   >
   > File "C:/1-Python/2-projects/最值.py", line 7, in findMinAndMax
   >   for i, in L:
   >
   > TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
2. My code

   ```
   def findMinAndMax(L):
       if L == []:
           return (None, None)
       else:
           max1 = L[0]
           min1 = L[0]
           for i, in L:
               if i >= max1:
                   max1 = i
               elif i <= min1:
                   min1 = i

           return (min1, max1)


   if findMinAndMax([]) != (None, None):
       print('test failed!')
   elif findMinAndMax([7]) != (7, 7):
       print('test failed!!')
   elif findMinAndMax([7, 1]) != (1, 7):
       print('test failed!!')
   elif findMinAndMax([7, 1, 3, 9, 5]) != (1, 9):
       print('test failed!!')
   else:
       print('test success!!')
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the comma in the for loop:

```
...
for i in L:
    ...
```

Comment: I feel so embarrassed that I made such a stupid mistake.Anyway,thanks a lot.^_^

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use a different code:

```
def findMinAndMax(L):
    if L == []:
        return (None, None)
    return (min(L), max(L))
```

Simple, isn't it?